# Case insensitive order_by in sql - Codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I am sorting while select ascending it, it works but i want it as case insensitive. Sorting on column Username.

my code

```
$this->db->order_by('client_name','asc');
```

Currently it display like this.

```
user_id | code |username
1   A   AAAA
2   B   BBBB
3   C   acac
4   D   cccc
```

Expected output

```
user_id | code |username
1   A   AAAA
2   B   acac
3   C   BBBB
4   D   cccc
```

Comment: I take it the column's collation is something binary? You could order by raw -- "order by username collate utf8_general_ci" -- this is assuming you can order by raw SQL. I'm not familiar with Codeigniter, so not posting this as an answer. Otherwise, changing your collation to something non-binary should make MySQL sort case insensitive by default (unless Codeigniter is doing something like order by binary username) -- again, this is why I'm not posting an answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have changed my collate to utf8_general_ci and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query:-

```
SELECT * FROM TAB ORDER BY LOWER(USER_NAME);
```

SQL Fiddle is here.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/088caa/1

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of options here:

```
“SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY client_name COLLATE ‘latin1_general_ci’ ASC;

“SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY LOWER(client_name) ASC"
```

Both of these mean not changing the schema in the database and if you have selected the correct schema originally this is preferable.

Otherwise changing the schema to `latin1_general_ci` will work well but yet again this is not always a) an option or b) feasible due to other data restrictions.

Answer (score -1):

$this->db->order_by("(CASE caller_status
                   When 'field values 1' Then 1
                   When 'field values 2' Then 2
                   When 'field values 3' Then 3
                   Else 4 End)");